# With ViewPager and PagerAdapter, how to remove Item at position '0' with Current Item of '0'?

Tags: android, position, android-viewpager

I am using the ViewPager with PagerAdapter from android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Library, I want to remove the number zero Item if List, when my current Item is also number zero. I can remove it without any error, but the screen does not refresh instantly. If I go to Item 2 and come back, then the Item zero is updated. Can anybody solve this problem?

I am using the remove-function below:

```
public View removePage(int position) {
        if ((position < 0) || (position >= getSize()) || (getSize()<=1)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (position == mPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                if(position == (getSize()-1)) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(position-1);
                } else if (position == 0){
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
            }
            View tempView = myPagerAdapter.mListViews.remove(position);
            myPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return tempView;
        }
    }
```

And I guess the problem should happened in the function call of

```
setCurrentItemInternal(newCurrItem, false, true);
```

with the parameter of newCurrItem of '0', and mCurItem of '0' in ViewPager.java. Further more, the trouble should be in either completeScroll(); or scrollTo(destX, 0); at the end of setCurrentItemInternal();

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same question now! Faced this problem last night and I couldn't work my way around it.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

> public void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)
>
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
>   of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
>   place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
>   perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
>   a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
>   less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
>   the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
>   layouts. This setting defaults to 1.
>
> Parameters limit  How many pages will be kept offscreen in an idle
>   state.

Set the **OffScreenPageLimit** to zero and than remove the item. You can set **OffScreenPageLimit** to 1 (default) again.

Comment: Setting page limit to zero isn't working.
Please check out the code which I brought from ViewPager.java

public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
  if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " + DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
    limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
        }
............
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java